# How to cross iterate two arrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two `arrayLists` for now, and I want to do cross-iterations of them (basically, first iterate the 1st element in the first `arrayList`, and then iterate the 1st element in the second `arrayList`, next iterate the 2nd element in the first `arrayList` etc.). I am wondering how should I achieve this functionality?

Here is a simple test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList first = new ArrayList();

        first.add("a");
        first.add("c");
        first.add("e");

        ArrayList second = new ArrayList();

        second.add("b");
        second.add("d");

        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);

    }
```

So basically, I would like to first extract the String `a` and do some coding, then String `b`, then String `c`, then `d` and `e` (note that the number of elements in the second arrayList is always one smaller then the first one).

Any hints will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Why not concatenate both lists and sort them and after iterate it?

Comment: What is exactly your use case? What is the idea behind joining the lists in that specific way?

Comment: Hi @KunLun, because the method I will do with the String will be different. In this example let's say, I would like to extract `a` and do smth like `toUpperCase`, but for `b` I would like to do `toLowerCase`. Just an example, my actual coding will be much complex than this :) Hope that explain your question?

Comment: Hi @JoãoDias, in my case, arrayList `first` will be the activity of one person, and arrayList `second` will be the move of that person. So I would like to depict the activity chain of this person in a day, so I need to first extract the first element in the first one, then first element in the second one, then second element in the first one etc. :) Hope that help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate both lists from 0 until to `second.size()`, as you said second is always smaller.

And with a second `for-loop` iterate the rest elements from `second.size()` until to `first.size()`

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
first.add("a"); first.add("c");
first.add("e"); first.add("f");
first.add("g");

ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
second.add("b");second.add("d");

for(int i = 0; i < second.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(first.get(i).toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(second.get(i).toLowerCase());
}

//iterate the rest elements remained in first
for(int i = second.size(); i < first.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(first.get(i).toUpperCase());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the explanation given in one of the comments, the List `first` should be renamed to `actions` and the List `second` should be `moves`.
Further there is always one final `action` after the last `move`, and the processing always starts with an action.

Try this (but replace the '?' by something useful first):

```
public final void process( final List<?> a, final List<?> m )
{
  if( a.size() != m.size() + 1 ) throw IllegalArgumentException( … );
  final Queue<?> actions = new LinkedList<>( a );
  final Queue<?> moves = new LinkedList<>( m );
  
  while( !moves.isEmpty() )
  { 
    final var action = actions.remove();
    final var move = moves.remove();

    doAction( action );
    doMove( move );
  }
  final var action = actions.remove();
  doAction( action );
  
  assert actions.isEmpty();
  assert moves.isEmpty(); 
}
```

Call this as

```
process( first, second );
```

Of course you can avoid the the local variables by using the return value from `Queue.remove()` as the argument to the `do…()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop with  two counters and iterate from 0 to first.length

counterForFirst ( i in the foor loop ) = 0;
counterForSecond = 0;

inside the loop, you would increment counterForSecond as well.

To avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
you could check if(counterForSecond < second.length ) in every itiration.

```
for (int counterForFirst = 0; counterForFirst < first.size(); counterForFirst++) {

         // action on first[counterForFirst]

         if(counterForFirst < seconds.length)
         {      
            // action on seconds 

              counterForSecond ++ ;
         }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that `first` list is larger than `second` you can just iterate based on `first` list size and then add the elements to a third list. You need to check that the iteration value is still applicable to the `second` list. Having said that the following should work:

```java
ArrayList first = new ArrayList();

first.add("a");
first.add("c");
first.add("e");

ArrayList second = new ArrayList();

second.add("b");
second.add("d");

System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(second);

ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
    result.add(first.get(i));
    if (i < second.size()) {
        result.add(second.get(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stream over the indices in the range between `0` and `first.size + second + size`. If like you said

> the number of elements in the second arrayList is always one smaller then the first one

then `first.size + second.size = first.size * 2 - 1` and even indices can be mapped to elements of first list and odd indices to elements of second list.

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
first.add("a");
first.add("c");
first.add("e");
first.add("g");
ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
second.add("b");
second.add("d");
second.add("f");

IntStream.range(0, first.size() * 2 - 1).forEach(i ->{
    String current;
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        current = first.get(i/2);
        System.out.println(current); // print or do something else with current
    }
    else {
        current = second.get(i/2);
        System.out.println(current); // print or do something else with current
    }
});
```